# Table border left and bottom

Tags: html, html-table

I need to create border as per the below example.

HTML:

```
<table width="770">
  <tr>
    <td>picture (border only to the left and bottom ) </td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>picture (border only to the left and bottom) </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 28):

you can use these styles:

```
style="border-left: 1px solid #cdd0d4;"  
style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cdd0d4;"
style="border-top: 1px solid #cdd0d4;"
style="border-right: 1px solid #cdd0d4;"
```

with this you want u must use

```
<td style="border-left: 1px solid #cdd0d4;border-bottom: 1px solid #cdd0d4;">
```

or

```
<img style="border-left: 1px solid #cdd0d4;border-bottom: 1px solid #cdd0d4;">
```

Answer (score 6):

Give a class `.border-lb` and give this CSS

```
.border-lb {border: 1px solid #ccc; border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;}
```

And the HTML

```
<table width="770">
  <tr>
    <td class="border-lb">picture (border only to the left and bottom ) </td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td class="border-lb">picture (border only to the left and bottom) </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FXMVL/

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I need. I should have mentionned that I am newby. I checked the link as well but don't get how to do that (sorry)
@Praveen Kumar : should I create a new css file and add:
.border-lb {border: 1px solid #ccc; border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;}
Then the html in my <body> ?

Comment: If you already have a stylesheet, you can add this. Else, add in the `<style>` part inside the `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the border property as seen here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pAzRF/)

HTML:

```
<table width="770">
    <tr>
        <td class="border-left-bottom">picture (border only to the left and bottom ) </td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td class="border-left-bottom">picture (border only to the left and bottom) </td>
    </tr>
</table>`
```

CSS:

```
td.border-left-bottom{
    border-left: solid 1px #000;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}
```